# Change executable path of app Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filenames

Hi I am a php Developer but yes i love linux.  I have a question.
I installed robomongo on my device .

To open it i have to do (from terminal)

```
cd /usr/local/bin/robomongo/bin/
./robomongo
```

I want to open robomongo when i type

```
robomono
```

On my terminal. How do i have change to path . Please explain step by step . SO i can understand and play around with different softwares.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `robomongo` script with the needed commands. The first line is used by the loader to find the right executable for the script. Later, the `$*` is replaced with the parameters. Make it executable with `chmod +x robomongo` and copy it to `/usr/local/bin`

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /usr/local/bin/robomongo/bin/
./robomongo $*
```